# NSUserdefault doubts

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

i have a view which has an option fullscreen view,i have done the coding with help of switchcontroller,but after fullscreen is switch to on and redirected to anotherpage and comes back it changes to default screen not fullscreen without swithcoff the switchcontroller,so i put NSUserDefault for storing the value but no luck this is my code

```
 -(IBAction)_clickbtnfullscreen:(id)sender
    {
        if(switchcontrolsplitf.on){

            [switchcontrolsplitf setOn:YES animated:YES];
//i put here the nsuserdeafult
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"fullscreenn"];
     CGRect frame = tab.frame;
            CGRect imageframe = btnShowHide.frame;
            CGRect viewframe = hideviewoftab.frame;
            CGRect lblframe = _lblshowhide.frame;
            CGRect lblmalframe = _lblmalaylan.frame;
            CGRect viewwframee= sliderView.frame;


            if (!self.isExpandedfullscreen)
            {

                btnShowHide.enabled  = NO;
                switchcontrolsplitf.enabled =YES;
                tab.scrollEnabled=YES;
                self.isExpandedfullscreen = YES;
                table.frame = CGRectMake(4, 48, 311, 20);
                if (frame.origin.y -=420) {

                    tab.frame = frame;
                }
                if (imageframe.origin.y -=420) {
                    btnShowHide.frame =imageframe;
                }
                if (viewframe.origin.y -=420) {
                    hideviewoftab.frame =viewframe;
                }
                if (lblframe.origin.y -=420) {
                    _lblshowhide.frame =lblframe;
                }
                if (viewwframee.origin.y -=420) {
                    sliderView.frame =viewwframee;
                }
                if (lblmalframe.origin.y -=420) {
                    _lblmalaylan.frame =lblmalframe;
                }
            }
        }
       else 
            {
                CGRect frame = tab.frame;
                CGRect imageframe = btnShowHide.frame;
                CGRect viewframe = hideviewoftab.frame;
                CGRect lblframe = _lblshowhide.frame;
                CGRect lblmalframe = _lblmalaylan.frame;
                CGRect viewwframee= sliderView.frame;
               self.isExpandedfullscreen = NO;

            [switchcontrolsplitf setOn:NO animated:YES];
            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"lowlight"];

            tab.scrollEnabled=NO;
            switchcontrolsplitf.enabled =YES;
            table.frame = CGRectMake(4, 48, 311, 387);
            btnShowHide.enabled  = YES;
            if (frame.origin.y +=420) {

                tab.frame = frame;
            }
            if (imageframe.origin.y +=420) {
                btnShowHide.frame =imageframe;
            }
            if (viewframe.origin.y +=420) {
                hideviewoftab.frame =viewframe;
            }
            if (lblframe.origin.y +=420) {
                _lblshowhide.frame =lblframe;
            }
            if (viewwframee.origin.y +=420) {
                sliderView.frame =viewwframee;
            }
            if (lblmalframe.origin.y +=420) {
                _lblmalaylan.frame =lblmalframe;
            }

        }
```

in viewwillappear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  BOOL fullscreenn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"fullscreenn"];
    if (fullscreenn) {
       [switchcontrolsplitf setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
```

How to solve this.please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Try to print boolean value on console you can better track the problem then ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after setting your value, you need to [synchronize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) i.e. save it

```
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"fullscreenn"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: only get the switch to on when redircted and returns back,but the view is still in default mode

Comment: can you reformulate that? from your question and comment. i don't get it what your problem is.